# Magento: moving a cms block to top

Tags: php, xml, facebook, magento, block

I'm new to Magento and after some struggle I've managed to create a CMS block for my Facebook Likebox and get it to display on the catalogs sidebar by editing the `2columns-right.phtml.` where i inserted the following code:`

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('fbfanbox')->toHtml() ?>
```

`

However the likebox is displayed all the way at the botttom and don't know how to change it's order to move it upwards.
After some research I've came to the conclusion that I have to look at `catalog.xml` for CMS block ordering.
I know the block code line should be something like :

```
<block type="cms/block" name="fbfanbox" before="-" template="don't know what to put here"/>
```

but I don't where in the catalog.xml to put it and what to put in template="".

My catalog.xml looks like:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
```

```
<default>

    <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <reference name="right">
        <!--<block type="core/template" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
            <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_left_callout.jpg</src></action>
            <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Our customer service is available 24/7. Call us at (555) 555-0123.</alt></action>
            <action method="setLinkUrl"><url>checkout/cart</url></action>
        </block>-->
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" after="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <!--<block type="core/template" name="right.permanent.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml">
            <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_right_callout.jpg</src></action>
            <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Keep your eyes open for our special Back to School items and save A LOT!</alt></action>
        </block>-->
    </reference>
    <reference name="footer_links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map"><label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /><title>Site Map</title></action>
    </reference>
    <block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" />
</default>
```

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Hopefully someone will manage to help since it's the last step towards launching the website.

Answer (score 0):

Place it in the beginning of `<reference name="right">` in your catalog.xml and define before attribute this way

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="cms/block" name="fbfanbox" before="cart_sidebar">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>fbfanbox</block_id></action>
    </block>
...
```